# Struggling to find solution: question 4 (Ordinary Differential equation) (Reducible exact equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could someone please help with this problem?
$$(2y+\frac{y^2}{x})dx+(2y+x)dy=0$$
I have tried and found the integrating factor $F(x)= 1/x$ and then re-arranged the equation to be:
$$(2\frac{y}{x}+\frac{y^2}{x^2})dx+(2\frac{y}{x}+1)dy=0$$
After this point it seemed so similar to a reducible seperable equation so I did this:
$$y=ux$$ $$y'=u'x+u$$
With this transformation
$$\frac{du}{dx}x+u=-\frac{2u+u^2}{2u+1}$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}x=-u-(u+1-\frac{1}{2u+1})$$

Comment: Your denominator is wrong: It should be $2u+1$ since the ODE is $\left(2\frac{y}{x}+\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)dx+\left(\color{red}2\frac{y}{x}+1\right)dy=0$

Comment: What do you mean you are stuck? You are already done. Simplify the right hand side.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Oh yes, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(2y+\frac{y^2}{x})dx+(2y+x)dy=0$$
$$(2xy+{y^2})dx+(2xy+x^2)dy=0$$
$$ydx^2+y^2dx+xdy^2+x^2dy=0$$
$$(ydx^2+x^2dy)+(y^2dx+xdy^2)=0$$
$$d(yx^2)+d(y^2x)=0$$
Integrate:
$$yx^2+y^2x=C$$
$$xy(x+y)=C$$

Answer (score 1):

Your denominator is wrong: it should be $2u+1$ since the ODE is $\left(2\frac{y}{x}+\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)dx+\left(\color{red}2\frac{y}{x}+1\right)dy=0$.

It simplifies to $u'x=-u-\frac{2u+u^2}{2u+1}=-3\left(\frac{u^2+u}{2u+1}\right)$, which is variable separable.

We get $\int\frac{2u+1}{u^2+u}~du=-3\int\frac{dx}x$.

To integrate, take $m=u^2+u$. Can you complete?

> $$\begin{align*}&m=u^2+u\implies dm=(2u+1)du\\\implies&\int\frac{dm}m=-3\int\frac{dx}x\\\implies&mx^3=k\\\implies&(y^2+xy)x=k\end{align*}$$

Comment: These simple mistakes are killing me